# How to fix undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newOptions.merge')?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am writing angular 2 app. This test is created by angular cli and fails by default:

```
  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');
  }));
```

Error message is:

> Failed: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:51:14 caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newOptions.merge')
>   mergeOptions@webpack:///~/@angular/http/src/http.js:47:0 <- src/test.ts:69434:22
>   get@webpack:///~/@angular/http/src/http.js:147:0 <- src/test.ts:69534:110

As I can found `newOptions.merge` is called from `mergeOptions` method inside `node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.js`.

What I have to do in order to make tests passing?

Here is [gist fro app.component.ts](https://gist.github.com/gandra/9568daccd306faa6b59b7a06c11c5efc)
Her is [gist for app.component.html](https://gist.github.com/gandra/f2d0ef1517725fd17c9f1fa7e0f7812d)

Comment: Please post the contents of your AppComponent. We need to see it in order to be able to say why this test is failing

Comment: @JesseCarter, I have added gist in issue text at the end.

Comment: Can you post component's HTML as well

Comment: @JesseCarter, posted gist for app.component.html as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Angular 2 Http service, so you need to inject *defaultOptions* parameter, which is, in your case, empty.

Best scenario to make this work is to add the following lines in your spec.ts file:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{
                provide: Http,
                useFactory: (
                    backend: ConnectionBackend, 
                    defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions
                ) => {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                },
                deps: [BaseRequestOptions]
            },
            {
                provide: BaseRequestOptions,
                useClass: BaseRequestOptions
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

So, the line when you tell that provider BaseRequestOption uses class BaseRequestOptions is crucial.

Comment: This does not solve the issue, is there something else which needs to changed?